Update subscription price for all customers in Stripe
I wanted to update price on Stripe subscription. To do that I added new price on Stripe dashboard and overwrite price ID in application code. It works fine for new customers but I don't know how to adjust it for customers who bought subscription for old price. How to swap them to use new price?

I've had a similar problem in a project of mine. Updating the existing price of a subscription was not possible, so the solution was to create a new price, iterate over all phases of the affected subscriptions, and replace the existing price with the new one.
